# git rebase: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout (though files are tracked)

Tags: git, rebase

When attempting an interactive rebase, git says:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
        # some files here
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting
error: could not detach HEAD
```

The set of files in question seem to vary depending on which commits I mark for (e)dit. They are all tracked files that have been modified along the commits in the branch, then finally removed in a subseqent commit.

Why is git doing this? How do I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Git is complaining because the files are untracked.

I know you said:

> [the] files are tracked

but they aren't: you also said:

> They are ... finally removed in a subsequent commit.

When you are at the point where the failure occurs, the files have been removed from the index, but not from the work-tree.  That's the definition of an *untracked file:* it is a file that is in the work-tree, but not in the index.

Specifically, this:

> ```
> error: could not detach HEAD
> ```

tells you (or me, anyway) that the files are currently untracked in the tip commit you have checked out right now, as you enter the command:

```
git rebase -i <start-point>
```

but the commit identified by <start-point> here has them in it.  Git will need to `git checkout` that commit, but in checking out that commit, it will overwrite the untracked files with the tracked files.

If that last bit gave you a [record-scratch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z_rBo-M9MgY) / WTF noise in your head  don't worry: it really *is* confusing.

The index, in Git, is a crucial little beastie that is often not explained properly.  To understand it, you have to realize that Git has, at all times, *three*—well, *up to* 3—copies of each file that you're working on/with.  One copy is frozen for all time, in a commit: the commit you have checked out right now.  A second copy<sup>1</sup> lives in the *index*.  It's what makes the file *tracked*.  The third copy is the only one you can *see* ... but **Git doesn't even use it** as it's *your* copy, in your work-tree.

The index, which Git also calls the *staging area*, holds a copy (see footnote 1 again) of each file that will go into the *next commit you make*.  As such, it's originally copied *out* of the commit you `git checkout`, as you pick a commit to work on.  Git then copies the index copy, which is in a special Git format, out your *work-tree*, which is where Git puts all the snapshot files for you to see and work with.

Once Git has copied these out, it's mostly done with them.  You make changes to your work-tree copy, and then run `git add` to tell Git: *copy the work-tree copy back into / over top of the index copy*.  (Again, see footnote 1.)  The reasons for this are a bit complicated, but if you like, think of it this way:

- The copies in commits are read-only, frozen for all time.  To save a lot of space, Git keeps them in a special Git-only compressed format, that only Git can use.
- This makes sense for archival but is useless for getting *work* done, so Git has to expand out the file to its normal form.  That's the *work-tree* copy.
- To make things go fast and make things convenient for Git, Git keeps the frozen copy (but not frozen any more) in the index.  You can replace the index copy wholesale, by `git add`-ing from the work-tree: Git will get it into the freeze-dried *format*, ready to be committed, in the index (but it's still replaceable there).

You can do anything you want with the work-tree copy, because it's a regular file.  As long as the work-tree file exists, it's just there, as a file.

You can *remove or replace* the index copy any time.  To replace it, use `git add` to copy the work-tree file back over whatever is in the index, under that name.  To remove it entirely, use `git rm file`.

When you run `git commit`, Git packages up *all the files that are in the index* to make the new commit's snapshot.  Whatever is in the index—in whatever form it has in the index—goes into the new commit.  Git doesn't use your work-tree for this at all.  That's why you have to re-`git-add` files all the time: Git isn't looking at the work-tree copy.<sup>2</sup>

If the work-tree file exists and the index copy is *gone*, the file is *untracked*.  But if the file is in some earlier *commit* and you check out that commit, the copy from the earlier commit goes *back into* the index, and the file is tracked again.  And, when the copy from the earlier commit goes into the index, Git will overwrite the copy in the work-tree too—unless that would trash it because it's not saved anywhere, in which case, Git says that it's in the way.

(If it's tracked, Git knows if it's safely saved in a commit.  If so, Git can overwrite it.)

So, what to do about this should be obvious now: if the data are important, move the files somewhere else.  Do your rebase.  When you're done, the files will be *gone* because the last commit removes them.  Now you can move the files back and they're untracked again.  The commits that had the files earlier still have the files now; if your rebase copied those commits to new-and-improved commits, those new-and-improved commits still have the files.

**Key concept:** whether a file is *tracked* or *untracked* depends on whether there is a copy in the index.  The index copy is mostly invisible,<sup>3</sup> but it's vitally important!  **The index is a temporary area.**  It mostly contains the *next* commit you will make; Git has to *fill it in* from a commit when you `git checkout` that commit.

Hence, the tracked/untracked state of some file can suddenly change.  When Git is filling the index *from* a commit, it will create a file in the index if needed *and* create it in the work-tree at that time; or, it will *remove* a file from the work-tree if needed—if it's not in the commit you're moving to—and at that time, it will *remove* the file *from* the work-tree, too.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, the index contains a *reference* to a blob object, for each file to be committed.  The blob object is frozen for all time and commits refer to it, just like the index did.  When you `git add` a file, Git compresses and hashes the content, and if there's already a blob with that data, Git can re-use the existing blob.  Otherwise Git makes a new one and that blob's hash goes into the index.

Sometimes this creates a blob that never gets used, because you write one version in, then realize there's an error in it and write another one in.  That's OK: Git creates garbage objects all the time, on its own.  Git has a *garbage collector* that it runs, whenever it seems reasonable, to clean out unused objects.

<sup>2</sup>If you use `git commit -a`, that creates a *second*, but temporary index, `git add`-s all the files to the temporary index, and commits from the temporary index.  If that all works, the temporary index becomes the new index; if it fails, Git simply removes the temporary index and everything goes back to however it was before you ran `git commit -a`.  The TL;DR is that Git is still committing from an index.  It's just a second, extra index for a bit.

<sup>3</sup>The `git status` command *compares* the index vs the `HEAD` commit and tells you what's *different*.  So if a file has "gone missing", you'll see a deletion as *staged for commit*.  Then, separately, it compares the index vs the work-tree and tells you what's *different*.  So, if a file is in the index but missing from the work-tree, you'll see a deletion as *not staged for commit*.

If the file exists in `HEAD`, but is *gone* from the index and then is *back* in the work-tree, you'll see a staged deletion *and* an untracked file, both with the same name.

Comment: Thanks @torek. Your reply made me realize: The files in-question have indeed been modified & removed, but I've created files in their exact location, with name differing only in casing (e.g. "FooDao.java" instead of "FooDAO.java". How can I fix this?

Comment: @pointyhat: By far the easiest way is to boot up Linux or some other system where these are different file names. For instance, on a Mac, use VirtualBox.  On a Mac you can also create a case-sensitive disk image and mount it, and then work in that file system.

Comment: On which scrollpage of your answer do I find concise instruction on how to avoid running into this scenario repeatedly at the same commit when continuously rebasing a topic branch on master?

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski: not sure what you mean by "scrollpage": the whole answer fits on the screen (just make the font size tiny)! :-) Unfortunately there's no simple recipe here other than to avoid ever having any untracked files at all. This is possible, especially with added worktrees, but not always practical. It may also require using a system with case-sensitive file systems, e.g., a Linux host.

Comment: My point is, since I am rewriting history by rebasing anyway, is there a way I can permanently "fix" that offending commit on the topic branch?

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski: If you're rewriting *all* history, you can use what you know of what systems you will support now and in the future to determine how to avoid having untracked file name issues in the future, in your existing (past and present) commits, and rewrite them, yes. However, this depends on perfect recollection of the future. I've never encountered that myself. The OP's problem was *probably* due to a case-folding file system (that seems to me to be the most common source of these).

Comment: Git really needs a better way to deal with these things. An example of a problem nobody realized was a problem until, well, it became a problem, is the macOS trick of normalizing Unicode file names. We can spell `schön` in two different ways in Unicode. Linux will let you use both, and make two different files whose names are `schön` and `schön`, that are two different files. Mac HFS file systems won't. This kind of thing results in future rebase problems on a Mac, sometimes.

Comment: (The two different spellings are: s c h o-with-umlaut n - 5 unicode code points total, and s c h combining-umlaut o n - six unicode code points. I can't remember off-hand whether the combining umlaut has to come before or after the o, though.)

Comment: Now that's a cämpfire störy!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have :

- a history of commits where file `foo.txt` was modified, then deleted ;
- at the moment, next to your tracked files, you also have an untracked verion of `foo.txt` on your disk.

In this situation : `git rebase` will complain, beacause it does not know what to do with the current (untracked) file `foo.txt` without erasing its content.